# CakePHP dynamic form inputs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 2.3.8 and I'm trying to create a form with dynamically added inputs from [this tutorial](http://waltherlalk.com/blog/dynamic-form-input-fields) but I'm having some issues. The adding and removing of inputs works just fine, but when I submit the form I get a black hole error message. Upon inspecting the inputs, it doesn't appear as if the key value isn't properly set and causing some issues with the id's of the inputs.

For example, with this code in an element

```
//Elements/users.ctp
$key = isset($key) ? $key : '<%= key %>';

<tr>
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->input("Role.{$key}.user_id", array('options' => $users, 'label' => false)); ?></td>
    <td class="actions">
        <a href="#" class="remove">Remove User</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

this is the select that is generated

```
<select name="data[Role][0][user_id]" id="Role<%=Key%>UserId">
```

**Edit**

The value of $key is being set correctly on /Elements/users.ctp. I can create a row and echo the output of $key, and a number for the row appears correctly. As you can see above, the name of the  element is set correctly, but the id is still being set strangely.

The name of the select element is being set properly, but not the id.
What is causing the select id to be `Role<%=Key%>UserId` rather than `Role0UserId`?

Comment: "I'm trying to create a form with dynamically added inputs ... but when I submit the form I get a black hole error message" - Generally speaking, that won't work. You can't use the security component (without fiddling with config) with dynamic form fields. Don't use the form helper to generate inputs that don't match the format of CakePHP (you're trying to inject a variable into the id - and the form helper is not designed to do that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Problem:**

If you observe the generated select tag you posted in question, it shows

```
<%=Key%>
```

The variable expected by underscore library utilized by the tutorial you are using is

```
<%= key %>
```

CakePHP form input is replacing the html characters and space of that underscore variable, hence its not detectable by underscore library.

**The Solution:**

In order to fix the issue, you must use plain html code for the template part. Your grades.ctp must be as shown below (partial code for understanding)

```
<?php if (isset($key)) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input("Grade.{$key}.id") ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input("Grade.{$key}.subject", array('label' => false)); ?>
        </td>   
    </tr>
    ...rest of the code
<?php else: ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" id="Grade<%= key %>Id" name="data[Grade][<%= key %>][id]">     
            <div class="input text required">
                <input type="text" required="required" id="Grade<%= key %>Subject" maxlength="200" name="data[Grade][<%= key %>][subject]">
            </div>
        </td>
        ...rest of the code
    </tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Using underscore for that seems a bit silly, it's _just_ copying a dom fragment and changing the id/name - (i.e. it's in principle `template = $('#Grade0Id').parents('tr'); copy = template.clone().find('input').attr('id', incrementIt).attr('name', incrementThat); copy.appendTo(template.parent());`)'. +1 anyway though, since that's what was asked.

Comment: Thank you, that's it! It never occurred to me that the form helper was probably sanitizing the data before creating the form. In the end I guess it didn't matter if I disabled the security features for this input anyway.

Comment: @AD7six. agree with you, for this minor purpose, underscore is not required, jquery is sufficient, I just answered the question.